# Extended Keyboard Number Pad issues?

Tags: keyboard, imac

I'm having an issue with some of the numbers on the "number pad" not working. Four of the numbers are working, but the rest are not. We plugged in another keyboard to test, which had the same issue. We restarted and cleared the PRAM (older INTEL iMac), and still no change. I've looked into the issue online, but many solutions are based on the entire number pad not responding. Has this happened to anyone else? If so, is there a solution to correct the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Get [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware) & see if they're registering at all with the Mac. Note that the numpad keys can be assigned *alone* to Key Commands [prior to Ventura] & are recognised separately to the numbers above qwerty - so there's a possibility someone assigned them as commands in System Prefs.

Comment: My iMac is running the latest version of Ventura. Could this still be an issue?

Comment: Have you made sure that Mouse Keys is turned OFF  (in accessibility settings)

Comment: @TomGewecke -  I hadn't considered MouseKey with the OP saying 'some numbers', rather than all numbers. I'm still waiting for them to come back with research I previously asked for.

Comment: Yes, "mouse keys" are disabled. In fact, I've gone through many YouTube tutorials that address this issue and dig into menu settings. The only problem is based on the entire number pad not working, not select keys.

Comment: @Tetsujin Does "Key Codes" work on the Ventura?  I can't seem to figure out the issue. I've plugged in 3 different keyboards and they are all responding exactly the same. The number pad only works with a few numbers and the others are dead.

Comment: It works fine in Ventura. Is it not reading those keys?